# How to connect multiple devices using built in hotspot of an android smartphone?

Tags: android, wifi

I wanted to know if there is an API that allows to create a hotspot and then communicate between the devices and the hotspot.

The Second thing is the number of devices which can be connected.

I have seen wifip2p but it says that it will not do it with hotspot and I need to do it using hotspot.

So I wanted to know how to establish the connection.
and the limit of devices to be connected as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible by wifidirect (Actually wifip2p). You can connect more than two devices. One of them act as server and other as client. The steps for connection are

1. Get p2p service
2. Search for peers
3. If peers available request connection.
4. If connection established then start sending string through Socket. (General socket programming)

The documentation for WifiP2p is

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

There is a demo for wifi connection and sending an image from gallery

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/

If you are interested in something like chatting with it you can look at following link

https://github.com/zahansafallwa/wifi-chatting-with-emoji

**Edit:About number of connections**

There is no limit of connection as per specification. But the data sending procedure is one two many in this case. That is there will be a group owner and all other will the connected to that server. Thus communication will be like

`member1< >groupowner< >member2`

This will deteriorate performance in great extent. But many claims the performance is more or less okey will 5-6 devices. In my case i got good performance upto 3 devices

Comment: technically there is no limit. but performance will scale down to a great limit. adding more to the answer in edit. have a look @hrishikesh10

Comment: yes it will still degrade some performance. but as your connection is only owner to clients you may try and see whats the result. if owner can just handle connection (be connected) to that great number of device then sending broadcast should not be problem. but as per i saw over internet no one could handle more than 5-6 connection with devices like samsung galaxy s4 @hrishikesh10